# Roblox age restriction not lifted when I turn 13

Tags: roblox

I had turned 13 last month and entered the exact date I was born in at Roblox, but Roblox still didn't lift the age restrictions. Is this an error, bug or what? I was looking forward for this restriction lift but it doesn't seem to happen somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a friend with this same issue, he ended up just creating a new account with the age set to above 13.
You might be able to send a support ticket the Roblox, but you probably won't get a response. Sorry, I don't think there is a way to lift the restriction on your own. Perhaps you entered the wrong date?

Comment: Roblox usually answers 1 - 2 days after the ticket is sent.